# Is there currently a known way to construct an injective mapping that transforms finite graphs into discrete geometric objects?

Tags: graph-theory

If there is such a mapping, it seems as though it could turn the graph isomorphism problem from a purely combinatorial problem to a discrete geometric one.

Comment: There is bijection from finite graphs to natural numbers.

Comment: ...So if a point with natural coordinates is "discrete geometric object", the answer is positive.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it seems like a fishing-expedition that has not been thought through

Comment: Yes, I think that's fair. I was just starting to think about different approaches to the graph isomorphism problem, and was trying to consider a nice mapping that would reduce the complexity of an algorithm which would check for isomorphism. I've made a bit of progress on this since the question was posted, but I agree, I hadn't given it much thought at the time.

Answer (score 2):

Map any $n$-vertex graph $G$ into a collection of $n$ points in $(n-1)$-dimensional space that are all at unit distance from each other, together with a line segment connecting two points whenever the corresponding two graph vertices are adjacent. Then two graphs are isomorphic if and only if the corresponding geometric objects are congruent.